# Add a path to include path

Tags: c++, macos, include

I'm on macOS, and for every library I install, the include files are in some different directory. The issue is, gcc/g++ looks only in the default include path.

How can I add another path to the include path? I have seem some other posts, but they barely tell me to add an "-I" flag to the compilation command. I do not want to add include paths for only one compilation. I want to make it so that this added path is automatically searched for *all* future compilations. How can I make it so?

Also, I have read some answers telling me to set CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH. However I don't wish to *change* the include path altogether, since the header files Ill be using are all in different folders, i.e. I want there to be *multiple* default search paths.

Comment: I would want all my includes to be symlinked to one directory rather than dealing with PATH multiplicities.